# WP Heartbeat API in Vanilla JS (addEventListener for custom events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Why following code written in jquery works great, but when I try to use it with vanilla js then it’s not working.

Here is WP Heartbeat API code - https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/heartbeat.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $(document).on('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('jquery');
  });
});




jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  document.addEventListener('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('Heartbeat tick JS');
  });
});


jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
var event = new Event('heartbeat-tick');
window.addEventListener('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('Heartbeat tick JS');
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `document` event is not firing because you are dispatching the event on the `window`. Call `document.dispatchEvent` to dispatch it to the `document`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var event = new Event('heartbeat-tick');

  $(document).on('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('jquery');
  });
  
  document.addEventListener('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('Heartbeat tick JS from document');
  });

  window.addEventListener('heartbeat-tick', function() {
    console.log('Heartbeat tick JS from window');
  });
  
  console.log('window');
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
  console.log('document');
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working, console returns: window
    Heartbeat tick JS from window
    document functions.js:603:3
    jquery
    jquery
    jquery
    jquery

Comment: If it helps here is wp heartbeat api code https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/heartbeat.js